# When formatting a string into fixed width columns, how can use use a different character instead of space to separate the columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6.13.  I'm trying to print a string into 2 fixed width columns.  However, I don't want to use spaces to fill in the empty space but a different character.  Is it possible to use a different character to do this?

This is the demo code I have

```
job = "blah"
owner = 'nat'

print ("{0:10} {1}".format(job, owner))
```

The output of this line is:

```
blah       nat
```

but I would like to print

```
blah.......nat
```

or something like this, using a different character instead of space to separate the 2 columns

Comment: Why not type it in? `print ("{} ..........{}".format(job, owner))` or even `job + "."*10 + owner`

Comment: @EliHarold, thx for looking at my question.  If this is in a for loop where the job and owner fields are different values of different lengths, it won't format nicely if you put it a fixed number of "." or " " or something.

Comment: `job + "."*10 + owner` does have a fixed number of ".", 10 to be exact. Both of my suggestions include a fixed number of "." but `job + "."*10 + owner` can be changed each iteration if needed.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do this:

```py
print("{0:.<10}{1}".format(job, owner))
```

Check out the [Format Specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for more info.

> If a valid align value is specified, it can be preceded by a fill character that can be any character and defaults to a space if omitted.